# Longest Common Subsequent output wrong result

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, subsequence, lcs

I've been trying to solve the LCS problem using recursion like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string max(string x, string y) {
    return x.size() <= y.size() ? y : x;
}

string find(string x, string y) {
    // Find longest Sub Sequence
    int firstSize = x.size();
    int secondSize = y.size();

    if (firstSize == 0 || secondSize == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    if (x[firstSize - 1] == y[secondSize - 1]) {

        char temp = x[firstSize - 1];

        return find(x.erase(firstSize-1), y.erase(secondSize-1)) + temp;
    }

    return max(find(x, y.erase(secondSize - 1)), find(x.erase(firstSize - 1), y));
}

int main()
{
    string x = "ABCBDAB";
    string y = "BDCABA";

    string result = find(x, y);

    cout << "result = "<<result<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm looks exactly, but the output is **ABA** subsequent that is wrong result, so something go wrong. The result is expected be a subsequent has length of 4 and I don't know exactly where I went wrong with the code. Why is it that ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? Try to perform the algorithm with pan and paper and compare it with what you expect and what your implementation does.

Comment: Yes, I wrote down on a piece of paper, but had too many sub problems and the result was also difference from compiler. Maybe I will try with smaller input. Thank for your advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit and let us go trough what I noticed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

I personally would've avoided question mark based return values in code, because they are not that readable, but this is just a suggestion.

```
string max(string x, string y)
//  Return biggest string
{
    if (x.size() <= y.size())
        return y;
    else
        return x;
}

string find(string x, string y)
//  Find longest Sub Sequence
{
    int xSize = x.size();
    int ySize = y.size();
```

Let's say the two string were both "ABC". Now the second if statement will return a find on AB call, which will return a find on A call, which will return "" as the longest substring of A and A, resulting in "" as the longest substring for ABC and ABC. Guess you weren't after this.

```
    if (xSize == 0 || ySize == 0)
        return "";
```

That's why I adapted the second if statement to what you meant, probably. Here you were erasing the last character, then adding the second last character back; I'm not sure if that was supposed to be, but since y[last] equals x[last], appending y after removing it's last with the last character of x is y itself.

```
    else if (x[xSize - 1] == y[ySize - 1])
        return find(x.erase(xSize - 1), y);
```

Then there was this variable only being used once: `char temp = x[xSize - 1]`. You might want to write it inline, so you don't have to make a variable and comment if necessary; but that's just code-style preferences.

```
    else
        return max(find(x, y.erase(ySize - 1)), find(x.erase(xSize - 1), y));
}

int main()
{
    string x = "ABCBDAB";
    string y = "BDCABA";

    cout << "result = " << find(x, y) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Try to structure your code a bit more, and now refine the algorithm, because there are some algorithm mistakes in it. Goodluck!

Comment: I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem. Finally, I solved it by replacing erasing the char  by using index m, n as parameters that represent size of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try without erasing the char and instead using arrays - `max(find(x, y[yIndex - 1]), find(x[xIndex-1], y))`.